# Does SSL / HTTPS increase site speed?

Tags: ssl

I noticed that our company website loaded incalculably faster once we installed SSL with EV.

1. Is increased speed an expected result after installing SSL?
2. Can I expect the same result if I install a self-signed certificate on `localhost`?

Answer (score 1):

A speed decrease is typically expected (but not neccessarily a perceptible one) - this is as a result of the additional overhead negotiating and computing the encryption.

You have not advised much about your environment, but I posit that your local network has a proxy or IDS system which is intercepting and dealing with HTTP traffic but not HTTPS traffic, and that may account for the speed difference.

Another possibility could be a badly set up web and/orDNS server and the SSL site bypasses the problem elements.  (It could be an issue with reverse DNS lookup for IP addresses for example).

A third possibility could be a change in hosting/hardware which occurred to facilitate the Secure site.

You would not generally expect a speedup from a self-signed cert on localhost or otherwise.  There is nothing intrinsically faster about HTTP over HTTPS assuming they are configured similarly, but there are things intrinsically faster about HTTPS over HTTP.

Comment: Your last sentence is a bit confusing. Please clarify?

Comment: HTTP and HTTPS work identically, except that HTTPS wraps the HTTP with encryption.   This creates additional work for both the cpu (to do the encryption and decryption) and network (to negotiate a secure connection).  Thus if you had 2 configurations identical in every aspect except that one had changes to support HTTPS the HTTP connection would always be faster - although not neccessarily noticeably faster.

Comment: You say "there is nothing intrinsically faster about HTTPS over HTTP... but there are things intrinsically faster about HTTPS over HTTP." I think there's a typo or something?

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing it out - tyats a typo, I'll correct it.

Comment: Is it now reversed from correct? Now it ends "but there are things faster about HTTPS over HTTP;" shouldn't it be the opposite? (it seems like you flipped the wrong one, saying HTTPS is inherently faster than HTTP instead of the reverse)

Comment: @davidgo: We use a hosting provider, which uses Apache 2.2.22 on Linux Debian 7. Just to clarify: our website is **faster** on HTTPS, much faster than when on HTTP. I just wanted to know if I could make the same thing happen to phpMyAdmin on localhost with SSL!

Comment: Someone/something is artificially limiting the speed of your Internet connection with respect of HTTP traffic - most likely a firewall belonging to you and/or a cache/proxy belonging to your ISP.  Attempting the same thing on localhost will decrease your speeds.